# Vaadin: respond to RPC calls

Tags: vaadin, rpc

I want to monitor and control Vaadin web application, and for that I need it respond to GET / POST HTTP outside Vaadin session handling.
I could do it as a separate service, but is there a simpler way within Vaadin?

Comment: It's not clear what you wish to do. And if vaadin is using websockets you have to look at them too

Answer (score 3):

Vaadin is optimized as an opinionated solution for UI. If you want to do generic request handling, then I would recommend a solution optimized for generic request handling such as JAX-RS or Spring `@RestController`.

Comment: I just want to poll status of web application with (typically) HTTP GET call. The solution is web app with UI build with Vaadin, so I am looking at a way how to implement it within existing codebase. If it is too complex, yes, the solution is to implement separate request handler.

Comment: @PeterBozek Adding a simple REST endpoint to Vaadin project using JAX-RS is super simple, see example here: https://github.com/TatuLund/cdi-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/org/vaadin/cdidemo/rest

Comment: There are also libraries that allow that.  E.g. if you are using Spring, you can use the actuator features to monitor health or query usage statistics.